# REPLACE new line character in MYSql not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I executed following query and for some reason its not replacing new line character in database . It says Rows matched 1 but no change . What can be wrong ?

```
mysql> UPDATE aboutme SET abouttext=REPLACE(abouttext,'\\n','') WHERE userid='5099a95cd944b8.22468149';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Is `abouttext` the column you want to store the replacement in? Are you sure you don't mean `question=REPLACE(question,'\\n','')`?

Comment: I think that the query found the row but it didn't make the changes because the 'replace' don't found `\\n`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can match a newline character using `\n`, not `\\n`.

Code:

```
 UPDATE aboutme 
 SET abouttext=REPLACE(abouttext,'\n','') 
 WHERE userid='5099a95cd944b8.22468149';
```

Comment: Can you match the row using a `SELECT`, such as `SELECT * FROM aboutme WHERE abouttext LIKE '%\n%'`? You may need to find the correct control character to match. See e.g. the code listed on this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 27):

If `\n` does not work as in my case, the following worked `\r\n`

```
UPDATE aboutme 
SET abouttext=REPLACE(abouttext,'\r\n','') 
WHERE userid='5099a95cd944b8.22468149';
```

In my case it has been a web application.

Comment: This is the right answer for me, MariaDB 15.1 on LinuxMint 21.

Answer (score 10):

You think that it contains `\n`, but it has `\r`.

```
update [Table] set [column]=replace(convert([column] using utf8) ,'\r','');
```

In your case:

```
update aboutme set abouttext=replace(convert(abouttext using utf8) ,'\r','');
```

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me was using this :

```sql
UPDATE aboutme SET abouttext = REPLACE(REPLACE(abouttext, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') WHERE userid='5099a95cd944b8.22468149';
```

Using Ryan' solution was not updating anything but was messing with MySQL output formatting

Answer (score 0):

this is what happening

```
mysql> mysql> select * from t1 limit 3;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS   | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG  | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        3 | ED         | CHASE     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update t1 set first_name=replace(first_name,'abc','') where first_name='ed';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 10  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1 limit 3;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS   | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG  | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        3 | ED         | CHASE     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> update t1 set first_name=replace(first_name,'ED','EDD') where first_name='ed';
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 10  Changed: 10  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1 limit 3;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS   | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG  | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        3 | EDD        | CHASE     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I meant is that the where condition it's working that's why you have 'rows matched: 1' but your replace don't find `\\n` to replace it, that's why `changed: 0` so check your table data.

Answer (score 0):

the REPLACE function is case sensitive, i think it belongs MySql server version

description=REPLACE(description, 'Videosite', 'video.5la.net')
is different result with 
description=REPLACE(description, 'VideoSite', 'video.5la.net')

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(text, CHAR(92), '#'), '#n', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way i found was:

```
UPDATE aboutme 
 SET abouttext=REPLACE(REPLACE(abouttext,'\r',''),'\n','') 
 WHERE userid='5099a95cd944b8.22468149';
```