# I want to export my MYSQL Table data in to csv format with | or ~ delimited

Tags: mysql, csv, newline, data-export

DB column data is multiline data , now i need to get result in single line

DB : Mysql
Table name :: master_countries

[image: db data]

so i want output in a single line comma delimited:

```
SELECT REPLACE(country, '\n' ,',')  FROM master_countries
```

Comment: Do you have linux or windows new lines? This thread might be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273343/replace-new-line-character-in-mysql-not-working. (I also would advise against this DB structure for this reason)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(country) FROM master_countries GROUP BY id;

Comment: `country` has multiple values in it, OP is trying to split on new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT REPLACE(country, '\r\n' ,',')  FROM master_countries
```

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(country, '\n\r' ,',')  FROM master_countries
```

Comment: in phpmyadmin choose export then csv then choose Columns separated with:|

Comment: The provide code doesn't change the DB data. It `select`s and alters on the fly.

Comment: ok , then  whats the issue ? is it not working ? SELECT REPLACE(country, '\n' ,',') if not try to put  also SELECT REPLACE(country, '\n\r' ,',')

Comment: I don't know, it is not my question. Just pointing out an issue with the answer.